# Changing the properties of a UIImageView

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, uiimageview

I have picked up programming as a hobby, so please bear with any 'old school' or completely wrong practices!

I am trying to move three images across the view using a timer. They then need to be dodged by another UIImageView. The obstacles are in an array:

```
objArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img-1.png"],
                                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"img-2.png"],
                                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"img-3.png"], nil];
```

I then have a for loop to create these views, and it's here that I think the problems start.

```
count = [objArray count];
for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
{

    NSLog (@"Element %i = %@", i, [objArray objectAtIndex: i]);

    randX = arc4random_uniform(450);
    randX = randx + 50;
    randY = arc4random_uniform(236);
    randY = randy + 45;
    imgObj = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[objArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
    imgObj.center = CGPointMake(randX, randY);
    [self.view addSubview:imgObj];
    [self startAnimation];
```

All three images display ok. The problem is getting these to move.

I understand the need for the timer, which is initiated in the startAnimation method. I have tried setting a tag in the for loop.  However this always results in the last object "img-3.png", which then moves ok.

My question is: how do I differentiate the three views I create in the loop so I can call them elsewhere?

Comment: `[UIImage imageNamed:[objArray objectAtIndex:i]]` does this work? Since objArray already contains UIImages and not NSStrings...

Comment: No, I guess I wasn't quite with it...

[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[objArray objectAtIndex:i]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning tags to you UIImageViews should work:

```
imgObj.tag = i+1; //skipping 0 here since other subviews may have this tag
```

Then you should be able to access the views via

```
[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
```

Or you could create another `NSMutableArray` and store the UIImageViews in it.

Comment: Created the second array as you mentioned. That was the right path to go down. Thank you!